# Quirk with .GLB files in Firefox

Tags: firefox, three.js, gltf

I loaded a .GLB into my Three.js project using Three's GLTF Loader, and the object worked perfectly in all browsers except for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox loads the children within the scene from a .GLB file in the opposite order of all other browsers. This is detrimental if you plan on manipulating the contents such as alpha maps, etc... of a .GLB object using Three.js.

I figured out the issue by loading a simple .GLB object into a project and it worked in Firefox just fine. So why wouldn't my more complicated object that utilized alpha maps work in Firefox?
Eventually I noticed that the children array of the GLTF scene was in the reverse order while running in Firefox thus causing my code to not match the indexes of the children.